installation of 22.04 on raspberry pi
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi and it refused to connect to the internet. The 400 has both WiFi and Ethernet.
My research has resulted in many options, so I learned more about the network handling structure in 22.04. Unfortunately, none of the options resulted in a cure.
Reference to one file revealed a possibility - /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml by adding this:
network:
  ethernets:
   eth0:
   dhcp4: true
version: 2

After rebooting, I was connected.
I hope this helps.

You can install Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 on your Raspberry Pi https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi/thank-you?version=24.04&architecture=desktop-arm64+raspi. It comes with a GUI, and you will not need to use the command line interface to configure network. Just use GUI like regular Ubuntu.

I am not seeing a question here. I am seeing an answer in search of a question. There are many possible reasons why a new install might not connect. A question that is useful to future readers will have enough detail to help folks determine if they have the same problem or not. Many won't.
